Running find on NFS mount much slower on RHEL8 vs RHEl7
I'm in the process of replacing some RHEL7 NFS server/client systems with RHEL8 systems, performing the same functions.
On the RHEL8 NFS client, I noticed running a find command on the NFS mount, is much slower than it is on the RHEL7 systems.

The RH7 and RH8 NFS servers are both exporting an ext4 filesystem.
The NFS content and mount options are the same on both systems.
The RHEL8 client defaulted to NFS v4.2, but I forced it to 4.1 for an apple-to-apples comparison.
The same slowness is seen with the export mounted with v4.2.

RHEL7 Client Mount:
RH7-nfshost:/data on /data type nfs4 (rw,relatime,vers=4.1,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,namlen=255,hard,
proto=tcp,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,clientaddr=xx.xx.xxx.xxx,local_lock=none,addr=xx.xx.xxx.xxx)

RHEL8 Client Mount:
RH8-nfshost:/data on /data type nfs4 (rw,relatime,vers=4.1,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,namlen=255,hard,
proto=tcp,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,clientaddr=xx.xx.xxx.xxx,local_lock=none,addr=xx.xx.xxx.xxx)

RHEL7 NFS Client - find strace summary:
strace -c find /data/dir1 -type d

% time     seconds  usecs/call     calls    errors syscall
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
 37.45    0.134456          48      2783           openat
 21.31    0.076496           3     25047           fcntl
 15.67    0.056269          10      5566           getdents
  9.51    0.034155           3     11143           close
  8.08    0.029002           5      5566           newfstatat
  4.50    0.016154           5      2783           write
  3.18    0.011422           4      2794           fstat
  0.07    0.000269           3        73           brk
  0.05    0.000184           7        25           mmap
  0.04    0.000155           9        17         6 open
  0.04    0.000129           9        14           mprotect
  0.02    0.000079           7        10           read
  0.02    0.000071          17         4           munmap
  0.01    0.000039          39         1           execve
  0.01    0.000038           9         4         3 access
  0.01    0.000020          10         2         2 statfs
  0.00    0.000013           6         2           ioctl
  0.00    0.000009           9         1         1 stat
  0.00    0.000008           4         2           rt_sigaction
  0.00    0.000005           5         1           rt_sigprocmask
  0.00    0.000005           5         1           uname
  0.00    0.000005           5         1           fchdir
  0.00    0.000005           5         1           getrlimit
  0.00    0.000005           5         1           set_tid_address
  0.00    0.000005           5         1           set_robust_list
  0.00    0.000004           4         1           arch_prctl
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
100.00    0.359002                 55844        12 total

RHEL8 NFS Client - find strace summary:
strace -c find /data/dir1 -type d

% time     seconds  usecs/call     calls    errors syscall
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
 91.54    7.621297          21    352681           newfstatat
  5.29    0.440847          53      8236           getdents64
  1.25    0.104052          37      2763         6 openat
  0.74    0.061794           4     13735           fcntl
  0.63    0.052231           4     10998           close
  0.39    0.032199          11      2747           write
  0.16    0.013517           4      2757           fstat
  0.00    0.000028          28         1           fstatfs
  0.00    0.000024           3         7           brk
  0.00    0.000015           7         2           munmap
  0.00    0.000007           0        21           mmap
  0.00    0.000006           0        13           read
  0.00    0.000006           3         2           ioctl
  0.00    0.000006           6         1           fchdir
  0.00    0.000000           0         5           lseek
  0.00    0.000000           0        14           mprotect
  0.00    0.000000           0         2           rt_sigaction
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           rt_sigprocmask
  0.00    0.000000           0         2         1 access
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           execve
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           uname
  0.00    0.000000           0         2           statfs
  0.00    0.000000           0         2         1 arch_prctl
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           set_tid_address
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           set_robust_list
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           prlimit64
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           getrandom
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
100.00    8.326029          21    393998         8 total

To me the issue is the huge difference in newfstatat syscalls on the RHEL8 client/server vs the RHEL7, but I have no idea why or where to begin troubleshooting.

Any chance you could report this to Red Hat?

In my organization, I personally don't have rights to submit cases to RH. I'd have to find out who in our org does. I'm not opposed to that, just thought I'd see if I could get this figured out here before I take that step.

Right, I know it’s not always easy. I could bring it up internally but it‘s always helpful if cases come from customers!

You assume that the problem is with NFS, but the difference in the system call of the find command might indicate the problem is in that command. First try to narrow down the problem. Copy the NFS disk to a local directory, and then try to compare performence and the find system calls on both machines. That's the first step. Then we know if the problem is more in NFS or in find.

Sorry, I should have included that running the find command on the RH8 NFS server itself (local filesystem), shows similar performance to the RH7 client over NFS, i.e. it's much faster than running find from the RH8 NFS client.

Of course that find will be faster on local fs vs NFS. It goes without saying. local will be faster than NFS. You're not comparing apples to apples. That's why I say you should compare local on RH7 vs local on RH8. If find on RH7 on NFS is fast, it should be even faster on local disk, which will show it's related more to find than to NFS.

The strace summaries running find on the local RH7 and RH8 filesystems are virtually identical.
